# MySQL the number is split

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a problem I'm trying to get data from a database.

I'm currently using `art.theme LIKE CONCAT('%',atheme.id,'%')`

art.theme returns a list of ids `51|61` I only need a way with `LIKE` to only keep the whole number and not a splitted number like `5,1`

Sorry if I'm not clear it's not easy to explain this.

Comment: The column names in your description do not agree with what is in your query.  Please fix that, and also show us some sample data.

Comment: You can use SELECT art.id,
        art.dateinsertion AS `Date`, 
        IF(art.actif = 1, "publish","future") as Status, 
        art.titre as Title, 
        art.chapeau as Excerpt, 
        art.texte as Content, 
        art.filinkimage as Mage, 
        art.rubrique as Category, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(atheme.titre_theme) as Tag
FROM AParticles as art
    LEFT JOIN AParticles_themes as atheme
        ON art.theme LIKE CONCAT('%',atheme.id,'%')
WHERE just4u_rubrique != "" AND atheme.id LIKE '%[0-9]{2}%'
GROUP BY art.id  
ORDER BY `art`.`id`  DESC

Comment: Fix you data model!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Don't store multiple values in a string column!  Your data model is broken.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it wasn't my database.. I had to get data from this broken db to create a new model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you only match complete numbers in your list, do

```
CONCAT('|',art.theme,'|') LIKE CONCAT('%|',atheme.id,'|%')
```

Another approach would be:

```
find_in_set(atheme.id, replace(art.theme,'|',','))
```